# Does WordPress do automatic upgrade?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am installing a fresh install of WordPress 5.9.3, as soon as possible I log into the wp-admin and I could check that is running the version 5.9.3, however, a few minutes later I can see that is running on WordPress 6

Does WordPress do automatic upgrades, if yes, how to disable it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about WordPress configuration and administration, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was add

```
define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', 'minor');
```